# How to get MAC-address in Rust?

Tags: network-programming, hardware, rust, mac-address

How to obtain **hwaddr** of first ethernet card?

And how to list all interfaces?

Comment: What platform do you want to do this on? I don't believe that there are any cross-platform libraries for doing this yet.

Comment: For example in python U can just do: `from uuid import getnode; print getnode()`

And yes, this is cross-platform method.

Comment: @Brian, in first line I need to do it on linux. In the first line on the ArchLinux on RaspberryPi.

Comment: https://github.com/dlevy47/rust-interfaces works on nightly, might do what you want

Answer (score 5):

On Unix-like OS, `/sys/class/net/` contains the symlinks to the available interfaces on your machine and the MAC address of an interface is written in a file  like `/sys/class/net/eth0/address`

On windows, I guess you have to parse the output of an external command like `ipconfig` to pick up your desired information.

A demo:

```
use std::fs;
use std::io::Read;
use std::path::Path;

fn main() {
    let net = Path::new("/sys/class/net");
    let entry = fs::read_dir(net).expect("Error");
    // a bit cubersome :/
    let ifaces = entry.filter_map(|p| p.ok())
                      .map(|p| p.path().file_name().expect("Error").to_os_string())
                      .filter_map(|s| s.into_string().ok())
                      .collect::<Vec<String>>();
    println!("Available interfaces: {:?}", ifaces);


    let iface = net.join(ifaces[0].as_str()).join("address");
    let mut f = fs::File::open(iface).expect("Failed");
    let mut macaddr = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut macaddr).expect("Error");
    println!("MAC address: {}", macaddr);
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong: On **Linux** you can use `/sys`, or more specifically, *on a system with `sysfs`*, of which Linux is one. BSD or Mac, for example, don't have `sysfs`, so it's not possible to access `/sys`.